# Structure of lazy loading in a lower level is correct?

Tags: angular

I've set up an angular 2 structure and I do not really know if I'm working with lazy load. I want my modules to be loaded only when it is needed. That is, when it is accessed via url.

There is the main module and inside this main module there is another module called admin. I perform lazy loading inside the admin module. But I stopped to think that the admin module loads fully when the user authentication. In which case, what is inside it is lazily carried?

Here's my code for you to analyze:

**my AppModule**

```
...
import {AdminModule}                  from './admin/admin.module';
import { AppComponent }               from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent }             from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent }          from './login/register.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ AdminModule ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent, RegisterComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**my app.routes**

```
...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];
...

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**my adminModule**

```
import { adminRouting }       from './admin.routing';
import { AdminComponent }     from './admin.component';
import { HomeComponent }      from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ adminRouting ],
  declarations: [ AdminComponent, HomeComponent ],
  providers:[ ]
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

**my adminRouting**

```
const imagesRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'images',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/images/images.module#ImagesModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

const updatesRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'updates',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/updates/updates.module#UpdatesModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

const adminRoutes: Routes = [{

    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [

        { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        ...imagesRoutes,
        ...updatesRoutes

    ]

  }];



export const adminRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes);
```

Comment: How are you building the project? Webpack, angular-cli, System-js?

Comment: thanks for answering. with angular-cli (Webpack).

Comment: I cant find any problems with what you have. What it looks like you are doing is lazy loading the UpdatesModule and the ImagesModule. you will be able to see this by seeing the chunks only get requested when you go to that page. A common problem is if you import these modules anywhere in the app chunk they will get eagerly loaded

Comment: If this is not working i suggest looking at something like https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: Actually, it's working. My question is whether the modules are loading lazily. I read in an article that to use lazy loading it is necessary to load at the first level of the hierarchy, that is, in app.routing.ts. I was wondering if I'm doing the right thing. How can I tell if modules are loading lazily?

Comment: Use the network tab on your browser.

Comment: Alternatively you can turn off lazy loading and inspect the bundle size and the loading time of the application

Comment: To see if your modules are lazy loading check the Network tab on Chrome. Also angular-cli will build separate chunks for your lazyloaded modules.